# Cocos2d-x Windows wav file too large

Tags: cocos2d-x, wav

I am porting my game on Windows phone 8.
My Sound files are mp3 which comes around 7.8 MB. Cocos2dx supports only wav format.
So its size is increasing to 80 MB in wav format.
Any Work around?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: App Size is increasing by margins :)

Comment: Are you certain it can only play wav, not mp3? Perhaps x supports ogg format?

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Audio_formats_supported_by_CocosDenshion_on_different_platforms
Here is link which says it supports wav and midi. App crashes when I use mp3.

Comment: Ah, found it. http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Audio_formats_supported_by_CocosDenshion_on_different_platforms Try ogg then. If that doesn't work either you may need to use native APIs. If that won't work either you'd have to live with either very, very low quality music to decrease the wav size (must be under 1 mb) or no music at all on win phone.

Comment: Lemme try ogg.. If that doesn't work.. M a dead man.. :P
See my game that I am porting... 
Android : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phonato.wickedchicks
iOS: Wicked Chicks.. :)

Comment: No support for ogg too.. :(

Comment: native APIs? Something equivalent to AVAudioPlayer for iOS ought to exist.

Comment: May be... Will have to see an option... 1 way is to reduce the size a bit.. As 2 Bg Music files are consuming more than 53 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You can save wav file with lower bitrate. It will reduce the file size while the quality will also be reduced.